# How to increase allowed disk space for Guest account

Tags: guest-session

Is it possible to increase the amount of disk space allowed to Guest account?

EDIT

df -h gives the following output:

```
guest-S9srd9@embsys:~/Desktop$ df -h
df: ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       228G   78G  138G  37% /
none            4,0K     0  4,0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            931M  4,0K  931M   1% /dev
tmpfs           188M  1,3M  187M   1% /run
none            5,0M     0  5,0M   0% /run/lock
none            940M  568K  939M   1% /run/shm
none            100M  104K  100M   1% /run/user
none            940M  557M  383M  60% /tmp/guest-S9srd9
/dev/sdb1       7,4G  555M  6,9G   8% /media/guest-S9srd9/8GB
```

df -i gives the following output:

```
guest-S9srd9@embsys:~/Desktop$ df -i
df: ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied
Filesystem       Inodes  IUsed    IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/sda1      15147008 237103 14909905    2% /
none             220402      2   220400    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev             215643    522   215121    1% /dev
tmpfs            220402    537   219865    1% /run
none             220402      3   220399    1% /run/lock
none             220402     11   220391    1% /run/shm
none             220402     56   220346    1% /run/user
none             220402   9114   211288    5% /tmp/guest-S9srd9
/dev/sdb1             0      0        0     - /media/guest-S9srd9/8GB
```

Comment: There should be no restrictions on Guest-accounts disk space, except the size of the disk hosting the guest users home directory.

Comment: I get `write error (disk full?)` although there is enough free space in disk.

Comment: Could you update the question with `df -h` and `df -i` done from a terminal in the guest account? And check in /var/log/messages and /var/log/syslog is ther are entries with disk errors.

Comment: @SorenA Please check the updated question. I added what you want to see.

Comment: @yildizabdullah the notice is not claiming the disk is full. It is a suggestion based on the fact there is a "write error". The way you word this question you make assumptions about the cause; please do not do that cuz it will have people searching for sollutions you do not need ;-)  That could also be a broken disk. `write error (disk full?)` should have been in the question. Plus also the -when- do you get this notice? If it happens during unpacking the archive is likely corrupt (so failing a basic crc check).

Comment: In other words: we can answer the "Is it possible to increase the amount of disk space allowed to Guest account?" but it is not going to fix your problem.

Comment: @Rinzwind I get `write error (disk full?)` while I am trying to extract an archive file. The archive file is not corrupted since I can extract it on another machine.

Comment: Are you tryinh to unpack in your home directory, on the 8GB USB (`/media/guest-S9srd9/8GB`) or .. ? Try to copy the archive file to your home directory and unpack it there.

Comment: @SorenA I did it already.